# docker compose - mysql - password

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose file

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: itaybeyder/mysql:2
    # secrets:
    #   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    hostname: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: run/secrets/MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD.txt

      MYSQL_DATABASE: crud
    networks:
        - app
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    command: --init-file /data/application/crud.sql

    volumes:
      - ./data/crud.sql:/data/application/crud.sql
      - ./data/MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD.txt:/run/secrets/MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD.txt
networks:
    app:
        external: false

# secrets:
#   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
#     external: true
```

and in the volume ( local folder in my computer ) i have password for mysql ROOT

```
volumes:
      
      - ./data/MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD.txt:/run/secrets/MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD.txt
```

i'm trying to pass it to the env - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD , but im getting error :

```
mysql  | 2021-12-26 16:27:10+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Both MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD and MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE are set (but are exclusive)
```

when im using **docker stack** its working but i want to use it with docker-compose.

**MY QUESTION** : how can i pass , password of the ROOT with the ENV

environment:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

with file that will be sitting in the container himself!!  , im coping file from the host to the container and i want him to read if from the local path , is it possible ?

**other way** , simplest , how can i transfer local password i have in the host to the ENV of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.env` file at same directory of your `docker-compose.yaml` file.

`.env`:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=SUPER_STRONG_PASSWORD
```

Then at your `docker-compose.yaml` you can specify it like this:

```
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

You can use `docker-compose config` to check if your configuration was applied.